# Solving an integral equation numerically for an unknown within the integral

Tags: integral-equations

I'm trying to solve an integral equation of the form `Constant == Integrate [g(x)f(x,Efermi), {x,-200,200}]`, for the parameter `Efermi`. The function `g(x)` is `Exp[-(x^2)/5000]` and `f(x)` is `1/(1+Exp[(x-Efermi)/25]`.

In addition to this, if the `Constant` is an array, I'd like to extract `Efermi` as an array. Any inputs on how to go about solving this would be appreciated.

Comment: `E==Exp[1]` so that is a bad choice as a parameter

Comment: `Integral`, `dx` isn't correct syntax. Is this a definite or indefinite integral? What are the limits, what are examples for `Constants`?

Comment: Right. I've edited my question for syntax. Hope the question I'm asking now is clear.

Comment: This is not really a Mathematica question. For the Mathematica part, you may use `Map` to get an array.

Comment: @Nasser Considering that he's talking about the Fermi energy, `EFermi` would be even better.

Comment: @Nasser well, you know my opinion on that. Honestly, I wouldn't write `kGRAVITATIONALCONSTANT` or even `GRAVITATIONAL_CONSTANT` as they're to long. However, I would add comments if I thought it was unclear what they were. For the Fermi energy, I tend to use `Ef`. But, mostly I was just having fun with your need to insist everyone start their variable names with a lower case. Ultimately, though my opinion is whatever works as _long as it is clear_. Of course, clarity depends on the [audience](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/02/is-there-an-excuse-for-short-variable-names/).

Comment: When the constant is an array is it a vector or a matrix? And what happens in `(x-Efermi)` does x also become an array, if so what happens to the integration region?

Comment: @Nasser you are right, clear is subjective, hence my comment on it depending on the audience. Here, the audience is fairly large, comprising numerous fields. So, clarity in that context is different than what you use in your personal code. I create functions that start with capital letters all the time, but I understand the risks. Clearly, the individuals in the link you provided did not, and, yes, I've had some of the symbols I use trampled on by newer versions. It encourages me to encapsulate my code better.

Answer (score 4):

For the scalar case:

Set up a function, `h`, depending on `EFermi`, and use `FindRoot` to solve `h[EFermi]==c`

```
Clear[g, f, h];
g[x_] = Exp[-x^2/5000];
f[x_, EFermi_] = (1 + Exp[(x - EFermi)/25])^-1;
h[EFermi_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[g[x] f[x, EFermi], {x, -200, 200}]
c = 100;
sol = FindRoot[h[e] == c, {e, 10}]
h[e] /. sol
(*  {e -> 55.2154} *)
(*  100. *)
Plot[{h[e], c}, {e, -500, 500}, Epilog -> Point[ {e, c} /. sol],ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: That was very helpful! Thank you!